# Prove That R and an open set has the same cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

-Prove  that R and the open set (-pi/2,pi/2) have the same cardinality. (*Hint: dfine the function f:R->(-pi/2,pi/2) by f(x)=tan^-1x. Then show f is well-defined, onto and one-to-one.)

-I am not sure how to prove a function is well defined. I understand that well defined means every point has a unique image,and I know it cannot be proved by showing a function is one to one.
I am unclear about showing how an inverse function is onto.

-Proof that f is one to one
If f(x)=f(y)
=>tan^-1x=tan^-1y
=>x=y
I think that this may be incorrect as well. but any type of guidance would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

For well-defined, notice $\tan(x)$ is one-to-one on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

For one-to-one, the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is positive. Or you can argue that since $\tan x$ is increasing on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so is it's inverse on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

For onto, it's more or less the definition of inverse tangent. Let $y\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then let $x=\tan y$.

Comment: I understand that tan(x) is one to one on the interval but do you have an idea how to prove a function is "well defined"

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a one-to-one function it means $f(x) = f(y) \iff x=y$. So $x=y\iff f(f^{-1}(x))=f(f^{-1}(y)) \iff f^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(y)$. Note this gives you one-to-one also.